# Set full border bottom for line break when use span tag in html

Tags: html, css

I want set underline for sentence but when it too long with width of screen, it will be break line to more line and will have spaces aren't set underline as red line of below picture. So how do set underline for all space?

My sample code in here: https://jsfiddle.net/hoanghoang3009/z5vjb3wf/

```css
div>span {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px dashed #b4987e;
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
        Xin chao tat ca moi nguoi, toi dang test thu gach duoi cua dong nhung chua thanh, cong. Neu thanh cong duoc thi qua thuc toi rat vui, va cam on tat ca so giup do cua moi nguoi.
      </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple trick to solving your problem.

In the parent element use the `overflow-y: hidden` and set ***border-bottom*** for it too.

And use the `position: relative` in the child element

And also for the text to fill the full width of the parent element use the `text-align: justify` as in the example below:

```css
        div{
            overflow-y: hidden;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            border-bottom: 0.5px dashed #b4987e;
            text-align: justify;
        }
        div> span{
            padding-bottom: 9px;
            border-bottom: 0.5px dashed #b4987e;
            line-height: 45px;
            position: relative;
            top: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<div>
      <span>
            Xin chao tat ca moi nguoi, toi dang test thu gach duoi cua dong nhung chua thanh, cong. Neu thanh cong duoc thi qua thuc toi rat vui, va cam on tat ca so giup do cua moi nguoi.
      </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it with background on the div element instead. You will also have better control over the dashes.

```css
.box {
  line-height: 48px;
  background:
    /* a white overlay to show only 1px from the border */
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0 47px,transparent 0 48px /*the same value as line-height*/), 
    /*the dashed border  */
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#b4987e 0 2px,transparent 0 4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>
    Xin chao tat ca moi nguoi, toi dang test thu gach duoi cua dong nhung chua thanh, cong. Neu thanh cong duoc thi qua thuc toi rat vui, va cam on tat ca so giup do cua moi nguoi.
  </span>
</div>
```

To have transparency you can consider mask like below:

```css
.box {
  line-height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #b4987e 0 2px, transparent 0 4px);
  -webkit-mask: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 47px, #fff 0 48px);
          mask: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 47px, #fff 0 48px);
}
body  {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>
    Xin chao tat ca moi nguoi, toi dang test thu gach duoi cua dong nhung chua thanh, cong. Neu thanh cong duoc thi qua thuc toi rat vui, va cam on tat ca so giup do cua moi nguoi.
  </span>
</div>
```